# Django - ManyToMany as hidden fields?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've implemented a multiple image upload method but I'm wondering which fields/widgets to use to be able to pass the image ids along with the form.

The images are added asynchronously while filling out the form and, on submission, these images would then be assigned to the object being added/edited by the form. How can I pass along this array of hidden fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the select in CSS, and let your javascript update the select's options.

That's what django-autocomplete-light widget does, and particularly in the case of the "remote autocomplete" which is like your case: js requests a django view that creates an object and responds with its id, and js creates the option with this id.